# Running a rails application inside a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, active-model-serializers

I have a rails application: `my_app` and it resides within the spec directory of `my_gem` for integration testing.

Here is the directory structure:

```
my_gem
|
|--.rspec
|
|-- spec
|    |----support
|    |        |---my_app(rails application)
|    |
|    |----some specs using rspec to test my_app                          
|    |              
|    |----spec_helper                
|    |----rails_helper
```

my_app is a very basic rails application:

my_app controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @example = //Model which subclasses active record
    render json: @example
  end

end
```

my_app Serializer:

```
class ExampleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id

end
```

my_app behaves as desired if I run it from the root of 'my_app' and all the tests pass when I run rspec.

However,
I have this scenario where I need to run rspec from the root of `my_gem` to make all the tests run using `my_app` as well i.e I am trying to run `my_app` from `my_gem`. In that case, everything else in `my_app` runs fine except for the serializers. 
The `render json` does not serialize the json

My guess is the serializer do not get loaded when I run `my_app` from the outside  gem. How should I configure my gem to make it run the rails application

Comment: You should setup your Gem as a rails engine unless you have done so already then setup rspec to use the dummy app - https://www.viget.com/articles/rails-engine-testing-with-rspec-capybara-and-factorygirl

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the only reason I am not setting my application as a rails engine, because I want to use the application to integration test my gem. i.e send in a http request to the application and verify the json response. Will this be possible using a rails engine?